# MongoDB shell error converting millisecs integer to microseconds and then to Date field

Tags: mongodb

Want to pass an integer holding microseconds since Epoch, to MongoDB shell's (version ~ 4.2) Date function to obtain a date. I understand MongoDB Date can take as argument, integer of milliseconds not microseconds, so need to convert from micro to milliseconds first by dividing by 1000.

Purpose is to add a date field 'new_field5' to collection, sample format below, *initialising it's value* from an existing integer field in collection called 'ts', which has epoch time in microseconds.

Step 1:
First tried converting a static value of microseconds to milliseconds in aggregration pipeline but all the dates are getting initialised as intial date of epoch.

```
db.mycollection.update({}, [ {"$set" :{"new_field5":  [new Date( [ {$round : [{ $divide: [ 1675750431775274 , 1000 ] },0]} ])] }} ], {multi:true})
```

Step 2:
Would then amend query to take the milliseconds integer from field ts

```
db.mycollection.update({}, [ {"$set" :{"new_field5":  [new Date( [ {$round : [{ $divide: [ "$ts" , 1000 ] },0]} ])] }} ], {multi:true})
```

Below works: if I start with integer containing milliseconds with no division required, the Date field is correctly derived from it. eg;

```
db.mycollection.update({},  {"$set" :{"new_field5":  [new Date(   1675750431775) ]}}  , {multi:true})
```

Collection layout:

```
{
  "_id": "nnn-f26c7979-99c8-4b27-b8e6-8f57e27c0fb4_1675750435048498",
  "sessionId": "nnn-f26c7979-99c8-4b27-b8e6-8f57e27c0fb4",
  "orchId": "orch-c9cd830e-917c-4021-b8ff-cecf1d534c34",
  "cvId": "cv-f26c7979-99c8-4b27-b8e6-8f57e27c0fb4",
  "vName": "orch",
  "data": "{\"text\":\"/inform{\\\"_MobileDevice\\\": \\\"apple\\\"}\"}",
  "ts": {
    "$numberLong": "1675750435048498"
  },
  "new_field5": [
    {
      "$date": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `new Date()` in JavaScript/MongoDB expects Milliseconds, not Microseconds. Why do you divide the value and then multiply it again?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have edited question as I had my micro and milliseconds described in problem wrong way round. I am dividing to convert micro to millseconds but where do you see I am multiplying it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$round` and `$divide` operators only have meaning on the server side, but the `new Date()` constructor will be executed on the client side, before sending the query to the server.

You should either use javascript functions to construct the date on the client side:

```
db.mycollection.update({}, 
  [ {"$set" :{"new_field5":  [new Date(Math.floor(1675750431775274/1000))]}}], {multi:true})
```

or use the `$toDate` operator to construct the date on the server side:

```
db.mycollection.update({},
[{"$set": {
      "new_field5": {$toDate: {$round: [{$divide: [1675750431775274,1000]},0]}}
}}],
{multi: true})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uJu5xH1zTDg)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the rounded value directly to the `new Date()`, not an array:

```
db.mycollection.update({}, [
  {
    "$set": {
      "new_field5": new Date({
        "$round": [{ "$divide": [ "$ts", 1000 ] }]
      })
    }
  }
], { multi: true })
```

Comment: this makes sense. However, after copying above and running, target field is still getting initialised with start of Epoch time. As stated before, the only thing that worked was passing a static integer of millis ( 1675750431775) which represents a date in 2023, to Date() function. That did initialise target date field with expected datetime. This suggest either of division, rounding or retrieval of the source field value "ts" is not happening correctly.

Comment: @JackA yes. I believe the issue is that the ts field is wrapped in a `$numberLong` object, which needs to be unwrapped before it can be divided by `1000`. You can do this by using the `$toLong` aggregation operator to convert the ts field to a long type : `new Date({ $divide: [{ $toLong: "$ts" }, 1000] })`.